# scipy sparse `LinearOperator` preserves sparseness under what conditions?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a `scipy` sparse csc_matrix `J` with `J.shape = (n, k)`.

Suppose `d` is some `k`-length array with no zeros.

I want to construct a `LinearOperator`, call it `linop`, where

```py
from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator,

J = # (n,k) csc_matrix
d = # some k-array
D = # assume I make a sparse diagonal matrix here of 1/d

linop = LinearOperator((n,k), 
                       matvec=lambda v: J.dot(v/d), 
                       rmatvec=lambda v: D.dot(J.T.dot(v))
                       )
```

My question is, under what conditions does this preserve "sparsity"?  Not of the result, but of the intermediate steps.  (I am unsure in general what happens "under the hood" when you multiply sparse times dense.)

For example, if `(v/d)` is dense, is `J` converted to dense before the multiplication?  This would be very bad for my use case.  Do I need to explicitly convert the input arguments in the `lambda` methods to sparse before the multiplication?

**Thank you in advance.**

Edit: pre-computing "`J / d`" is not an option as I need `J` later, and don't have the memory to store `J` and `J / d`.

Comment: No, J isn't converted to a dense array before J.dot(vector). J.T is a CSC matrix though and is cast into a CSR matrix (making a full copy) before J.T.dot(vector). The under-the-hood is a set of C extensions that are written as part of the scipy.sparse package.

Comment: Thank you!  @CJR !  Oh wow I did *not* realize that `J.transpose()` copies the full data (instead of using a view).  That seems pretty unnecessary, but on the other hand I guess scipy has no idea what you intend to do with `J.transpose()`.  I suppose it might be better memory-wise then to do `(v.dot(J)).T` instead of `J.transpose().dot(v)`?

Comment: `J.transpose()` just does a view (it makes a `CSC` matrix by switching the index pointers and the indices from rows/columns to columns/rows), but there's no dot product implementation for `CSC` so it has to convert that array via a full copy to a `CSR` for the multiplication. If you can avoid that, you probably should.

Comment: Thank you @CJR.  So if I understand you correctly, if `J` is an `(n,k)`-shape `csc_matrix`, then
[1] `J.transpose().dot(J)` will always force a copy of `J` even though *conceptually* it should be easy since we are just multiplying columns of a `csc_matrix` by other columns.  So I guess if I really want `J.T.dot(J)` there is nothing better to do?
[2] If I want `J.T.dot(v)` for a column vector `v` I should really make `v` into an `(1,n)`-shape `csc_matrix` and do `(v.dot(J)).transpose()` to be more efficient?
Thank you so much!!

Comment: You can dig down through `J._mul_dispatch` just as well as we can!

Comment: If `J` is a `CSC` matrix, `J.T` will be a `CSR` matrix and `J.T.dot(v)` will not require copying `J.T`. If `J` is a `CSR` matrix, `J.T` will be a `CSC` matrix and will require copying `J.T` for `J.T.dot(v)`. The specific code that calls the matrix multiplication is `return self.tocsr()._mul_vector(other)`.